# Whats your favourite number?

Tags: riddle, mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Matthew's favourite number is 47.

Jacob's favourite number is 17.

Tony's favourite number is 38.

What is Evan's favourite number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible answer:

> 22

Because

> Taking the position of every letter in the alphabet and adding the length, dividing by two and then subtracting 1 from the result gives the numbers for each name.

Example

> Matthew $\rightarrow \lfloor\frac{13+1+20+20+8 + 5 + 23 + 7}{2}\rfloor-1 = \lfloor 97/2 \rfloor -1 = 47$

Comment: You mean $\dfrac{a+b+...+z}{2} + 1 $?

Comment: Good job! That is the correct answer! I got the numbers a different way though this way gives the same numbers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @GamrCorps, how did you get the numbers?

Comment: @caonayemi I took the alphabet and mapped it to its number in the alphabet (`A=1, B=2, etc.`) then divided each number by 2 and took the ceiling (result was `A=1, B=1, C=2, D=2, etc.`), then I just added all of the numbers in the persons name.